# How to make a fixed "go to top" button on the page bottom, but above the (not fixed) footer?

Tags: javascript, html, css, footer, fixed

I have made a page (on Shopify) and I made there a fixed "go to top" arrow on the left bottom. It's okay, but when I scroll to the page bottom the arrow is will be in front of the footer, and I want it to stay above the footer.

Here is the code that I use:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {   
  $(window).scroll(function() {
    if ($(this).scrollTop() > 200) {
      $('.go-top').fadeIn(200);
    } else {
      $('.go-top').fadeOut(200);
    }
  });

  $('.go-top').click(function(event) {
    event.preventDefault();

    $('html, body').animate({scrollTop: 0}, 300);
  })
});
```

```css
.go-top {
  position: fixed;
  bottom: 2em;
  right: 0.5em;
  text-decoration: none;
  font-size: 40px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<a href="#" class="go-top"> &#x2191; </a>
```

Comment: play with z-index

Comment: set a windows listener, and when the page reach the bottom of the page, change the bottom property according to the page position

Comment: @ScottMarcus i don't this it's good to change his code to a snippet as there is nothing to see working ... i think code snippet should not be automatic for any code, it should only be mandatory for Complete working code where we can see a behavior

Comment: What about put $('a.go-top') as one child of footer?

Comment: @TemaniAfif It is a good idea to use a code snippet for three reasons. 1) we can now run the code and visualize the UI that the OP has made (that is working) 2) we can see immediately if there are syntax errors that perhaps the OP didn't spot and 3) anyone can now click "Copy snippet to answer" and create a fully running solution. Generally, there's not a lot of reasons ***not*** to use a code snippet.

Comment: @ScottMarcus but if you read again what you wrote you will understand .. your said `that is working` --> and here nothing is working, we don't have a full code to see a behavior or something working, also no need to copy the snippet to an answer since there is nothing working.

Comment: @ScottMarcus same thing with syntax error ... another reason to not made a snippet as if the OP have a syntax error because he didn't put **all** the code you can make his question bad as we will run something and we will have errors so we will think he didn't pay attention which is not the case

Comment: @TemaniAfif Come on, are you saying that you ***don't*** see a blue arrow on the bottom right of the running area? Are you saying that you can't tell if there is a syntax issue preventing the existing code from working? Are you saying that you don't see the "Copy snippet to answer" button that makes it very easy to create a running solution?

Comment: @TemaniAfif You'r not making a good case, sorry.

Comment: @ScottMarcus `are you saying that you don't see a blue arrow on the bottom right of the running` --> i see it and then :) is the jquery doing something ? you see the issue of the footer and the arrow ? no -- so the code snippet provide no behavior related to the issue

Comment: I'm sorry if i wasn't understandable. I thought it : 
[link](https://imgur.com/BrLcfQC)
[link](https://imgur.com/qAs8KbP) <-- with footer on the bottom

Answer (score 3):

```js
    $(document).ready(function() {  
      $(window).scroll(function() {
   //--------------------------- Lines added ------------------------//
       var footertotop = ($('.footer').position().top);
       var scrolltop = $(document).scrollTop() + window.innerHeight;
       var difference = scrolltop-footertotop;
      if (scrolltop > footertotop) {
        $('.go-top').css({'bottom' : difference});
      }else{
        $('.go-top').css({'bottom' : 10});
      };   
  //--------------------------- end ---------------------------------//
      if ($(this).scrollTop() > 200) {
          $('.go-top').fadeIn(200);
      } else {
          $('.go-top').fadeOut(200);
      }
      });
      $('.go-top').click(function(event) {
        event.preventDefault();
        $('html, body').animate({scrollTop: 0}, 300);
      })
    });
```

```css
.container{height:2000px;position:relative}
.footer{height:200px;width:100%;position:absolute;bottom:0px;background:red}

.go-top {
  position: fixed;
  bottom: 20px;
  display:none; // <---- Dont display on page load
  right: 0.5em;
  text-decoration: none;
  font-size: 40px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="container">
<a href="#" class="go-top"> &#x2191; </a>
<div class="footer"></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

add z-index to the css.
something like:

```
z-index: 100000
```

make the number as large as needed for it to be on top.

Comment: While this is the right direction, I would suggest using the lowest possible value to achieve the desired result to prevent a z-index nightmare. Consider wanting a pop/up modal, you'd probably want the "back to top" underneath it.